# java based web config with spring mvc 3 and tiles

Tags: spring, config, tiles

hear i have a problem to get mvc 3 and tiles working together

```
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.*;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"foo"})
    public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(final DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

and ...

```
  @Configuration
    public class ViewConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        return new TilesConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
        TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver = new TilesViewResolver();
        tilesViewResolver.setOrder(2);
        return tilesViewResolver;
    }
```

and following tiles config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">


<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="mainLayout" template="/view/layout/layout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/view/layout/header.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/view/layout/menu.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/view/layout/footer.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/view//layout/body.jsp"/>
    </definition>
    <definition name="test" extends="mainLayout">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/view/test.jsp"/>
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

here is my test controller

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

and here is output

```
DispatcherServlet.initContextHolders(986) | Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1b4c72c8                                                                                                                                                                                               
DispatcherServlet.doService(823) | DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/trd/hello]                                                                                                                                                                                                             
DispatcherServlet.getHandler(1088) | Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@eca5a40] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'                                                                                                                               
RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(219) | Looking up handler method for path /hello                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
RequestMappingHandlerMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(263) | Found 1 matching mapping(s) for [/hello] : [{[/hello],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}]                                                                                                                                               
RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(226) | Returning handler method [public java.lang.String ir.parsdeveloper.web.controller.TestController.helloWorld()]                                                                                                                                                           
DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBean(246) | Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'testController'                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
DispatcherServlet.getHandlerAdapter(1122) | Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter@6eb2756]                                                                                                                                                                
DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(912) | Last-Modified value for [/trd/hello] is: -1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
HandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(129) | Invoking [helloWorld] method with arguments []                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
HandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(135) | Method [helloWorld] returned [test]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.getReturnValueHandler(78) | Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ModelAndViewMethodReturnValueHandler@2903ccd9] supports [class java.lang.String]                                                                                    
HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.getReturnValueHandler(78) | Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelMethodProcessor@387dcf98] supports [class java.lang.String]                                                                                                                
HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.getReturnValueHandler(78) | Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ViewMethodReturnValueHandler@4bc82121] supports [class java.lang.String]                                                                                            
HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.getReturnValueHandler(78) | Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor@3ff72465] supports [class java.lang.String]                                                                                               
HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.getReturnValueHandler(78) | Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.CallableMethodReturnValueHandler@5979da9f] supports [class java.lang.String]                                                                                        
HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.getReturnValueHandler(78) | Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.DeferredResultMethodReturnValueHandler@4f002a9d] supports [class java.lang.String]                                                                                  
HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.getReturnValueHandler(78) | Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AsyncTaskMethodReturnValueHandler@6271edc8] supports [class java.lang.String]                                                                                       
HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.getReturnValueHandler(78) | Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor@4f432acf] supports [class java.lang.String]                                                                                                       
HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.getReturnValueHandler(78) | Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor@468f7aa2] supports [class java.lang.String]                                                                                      
HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.getReturnValueHandler(78) | Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ViewNameMethodReturnValueHandler@5522a7b5] supports [class java.lang.String]                                                                                        
DispatcherServlet.render(1206) | Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView: name 'test'; URL [test]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'                                                                                                                                                    
TilesView.render(257) | Rendering view with name 'test' with model {} and static attributes {}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(566) | No bean named 'requestDataValueProcessor' found in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5f1c34fb: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,webMvcConfig,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,viewConfiguration,testController,tilesConfigurer,tilesViewResolver,org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration,requestMappingHandlerMapping,mvcContentNegotiationManager,viewControllerHandlerMapping,beanNameHandlerMapping,resourceHandlerMapping,defaultServletHandlerMapping,requestMappingHandlerAdapter,mvcConversionService,mvcValidator,httpRequestHandlerAdapter,simpleControllerHandlerAdapter,handlerExceptionResolver]; root of factory hierarchy
BasicTilesContainer.render(615) | Render request recieved for definition 'test'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DispatcherServlet.initContextHolders(986) | Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@a750bb9                                                                                                                                                                                            
DispatcherServlet.doService(823) | DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/trd/view/thirdParty/layout/layout.jsp]                                                                                                                                                                                 
DispatcherServlet.getHandler(1088) | Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@eca5a40] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'                                                                                                                               
RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(219) | Looking up handler method for path /view/thirdParty/layout/layout.jsp                                                                                                                                                                                                    
RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(229) | Did not find handler method for [/view/thirdParty/layout/layout.jsp]                                                                                                                                                                                                     
DispatcherServlet.getHandler(1088) | Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping@696911f6] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'                                                                                                                                               
BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(127) | No handler mapping found for [/view/thirdParty/layout/layout.jsp]                                                                                                                                                                                                           
DispatcherServlet.getHandler(1088) | Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport$EmptyHandlerMapping@10f98160] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'                                                                                                                
DispatcherServlet.getHandler(1088) | Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport$EmptyHandlerMapping@6c9cce54] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'                                                                                                                
DispatcherServlet.getHandler(1088) | Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport$EmptyHandlerMapping@2aae2481] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'                                                                                                                
ageNotFound.noHandlerFound(1108) | No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/trd/view/thirdParty/layout/layout.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'                                                                                                                                                              
DispatcherServlet.resetContextHolders(996) | Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@a750bb9                                                                                                                                                                                      
DispatcherServlet.processRequest(951) | Successfully completed request                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.publishEvent(332) | Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/trd/view/thirdParty/layout/layout.jsp]; client=[127.0.0.1]; method=[GET]; servlet=[dispatcher]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[804ms]; status=[OK]
DispatcherServlet.resetContextHolders(996) | Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1b4c72c8                                                                                                                                                                                         
DispatcherServlet.processRequest(951) | Successfully completed request                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.publishEvent(332) | Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/trd/hello]; client=[127.0.0.1]; method=[GET]; servlet=[dispatcher]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[7716ms]; status=[OK]
```

i known that the controller is working propelry and return "test" as output
but when spring goes to find view have some problems.
i think the /trd/view/layout/layout.jsp will found but can't detect where resource is located.
i don't known more.
please help

Comment: I think you need to set the definitions of TilesConfigurer using `setDefinitions(String[] definitions)`. You need to pass an array of string telling it where to find the tiles xml configurations. Also normally tiles templates are jspx, I'm not sure if this would make any difference. You can see a sample working spring+tiles project by using Spring Roo: On STS (Springsource Tools Suite) create a new Spring Roo Project, give it a name, and on the roo shell run the command `web mvc setup`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell your tiles config where to find the definitions file.  You can either do  `new TilesConfigurer().setCompleteAutoload(true);` Which enables the complete autoload feature which will look through your `WEB-INF` folder for any definitions file(s) ending with `-definitions.xml` or explicitly point to your file `new TilesConfigurer().setDefinitions("path/to/defitions.xml");`.